# Send email when deleting events

Tags: email, events, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

so i have a form, form1, that creates google calendar events, and i log the contact email in the description of the event.

now i have another form, form2, that creates higher priority events, so that if form2 creates an event where there's already events, it'll get the email from the description of those events, email the contact person, and delete the existing events before creating a new event based on the information submitted from form2.

Here's the portion of the code that sends out email and deletes the events:

```js
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(startDt), new Date(endDt));
for (var i=0; i<events.length ;i++){
  if (events[i].isOwnedByMe()){
    var emnoti = events[i].getDescription();
    var message = "your event has been cancelled"
    var subject = "Event:cancelled";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emnoti, subject, message);
    events[i].deleteEvent();
    } 
  else {
    //do nothing
    };
};
```

the problem is that when there's multiple events, it doesn't get the contact email from the other events, it can only read the contact email from the first event (but it can delete multiple events no problem)

I thought the solution is `var emnoti[i] = events[i].getDescription();`, but this creates an error telling me `Missing ; before statement.`

So how do i fix this problem?

Comment: You need to debug your code with `Logger.log('var name: ' + variableName)` statements.  Add a line of code: `Logger.log('emnoti : ' + emnoti)` right after the line that gets `emnoti`  Run the code, and then VIEW the LOGS.  Is there a valid email address on every iteration of the loop?  The error message may be coming from something unrelated to the code that you have shown.

Comment: you have a condition `if (events[i].isOwnedByMe())` that say only handle event owned by me, so it's normal if it don't "get the contact email from the other events", it's always you, otherwise it  `//do nothing`

Comment: ah, ok, so the code is working fine, it's just that some events weren't owned by me so it didn't catch them. took out `.isOwnedByMe()` and it works perfectly fine now, thanks